# How long is a segment that is distant x from the triangle base?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have an isosceles triangle with height `h` and base `b`.

I need to know how long is a segment parallel to the base `b` and distant $h_i$ from the base `b` as depicted in the diagram below.

[image]

How long are $l_1$ and $l_2$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Extend the segments and look at the similar triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_1 = h - h_1$, so $d_1$ is the "depth" (measured from the top) of the first segment. Then a full-width segment at depth $d_1$ would have width
$$
w_1 = \frac{b}{h} d_1
$$
You can check this by plugging in $h$ for $d_1$, and seeing that the width you get is indeed $b$.

But you only want a half-width piece, so you get
$$
I_1 = \frac{b}{2h} d_1;
$$

A corresponding formula works for $d_2$:
$$
I_2 = \frac{b}{2h} d_2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider half the angle, θ, at the top of the triangle. $$tan\big(\frac{θ}{2}\big)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{b}{h}$$

Also consider, $$tan\big(\frac{θ}{2}\big)=\frac{I_n}{h-h_n}$$
Hence $$I_n=\frac{b}{2h}(h-h_n)$$ If you want a numerical answer you will need sufficient information i.e. two dimensions of one dimension and an angle.